# Como evitar que ao se inscrever em um observable ele receba o último valor emitido?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Tenho um `behaviorSubject` que emite valores e um Observable utilizo para receber os valores emitidos:

```
observableSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
observable$: Observable<string> = this.observableSource.asObservable();
```

Ao iniciar meu componente ele se inscreve nesse `Observable` através de um `Subscription`:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.mySubscription = this.myService.observable$.subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
   })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Atualmente quando o meu componente é destruído e iniciado novamente, ele recebe uma nova inscrição do meu `Observable`, ele tem como valor inicial o último valor emitido.

Há alguma forma de ao me inscrever em um `Observable`, ele não emitir o ultimo valor e sim o valor inicial `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão **BehaviorSubject** são **hot** ou seja tem esse comportamento de emitir o valor quando subscribed, por isso precisam de um valor pra inicializar.

No seu caso melhor usar só **Subject** mesmo que  por default são **cold**.

```
observableSource = new Subject();
observable$: Observable<string> = this.observableSource.asObservable();
```